# Why does an imported css file get stored in localstorage and not refresh like a linked css file?

Tags: css, caching, import, less

Files:

- listing.less (text/css)
- style.less (text/css)

Tools:

- Firefox
- Firefox addon httpFox for inspecting http headers
- Chrome

I have a css file named listing.less that contains the following:

```
@import "/orb/static/less/style.less";
```

When I call listing.less everything works fine, style.less is imported. Subsequent requests for listing.less results in a 304 cached response. That's fine. However, the imported style.less doesn't show up as a cached response. Instead, I find it in the browser's localstorage. The bigger problem is if I make a change to style.less then hit refresh the browser will not update the style. The style.less will refresh only if I delete it from localstorage or touch listing.less on the server.

Is that the nature of @import? Do I need to touch listing.less or delete style.less from localstorage every time I want to update style.less? How can style.less be forced to refresh?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a known issue in LESS. See the github issue here:
https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/47

I know it doesn't solve your problem directly, there is a workaround listed there, put the following line above your less.js import:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var less=less||{};less.env='development';</script>
<script src="less.js"></script>
```

and things should generally work.

Comment: +1 - but I got an error in Chrome 24.  I had to change the code to `var less=less||{};less.env='development';`

Comment: FYI: Setting the less.env property in development is good not just preventing localStorage cache.. it also enables a suite of debugging features such as debug messages (no more silent fails) and console logging.

Answer (score 7):

This is the approach I use now, because even in development mode, I find @imported CSS stays cached forever.

https://gist.github.com/1346280

```
// Destroys the localStorage copy of CSS that less.js creates

function destroyLessCache(pathToCss) { // e.g. '/css/' or '/stylesheets/'

  if (!window.localStorage || !less || less.env !== 'development') {
    return;
  }
  var host = window.location.host;
  var protocol = window.location.protocol;
  var keyPrefix = protocol + '//' + host + pathToCss;

  for (var key in window.localStorage) {
    if (key.indexOf(keyPrefix) === 0) {
      delete window.localStorage[key];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Or you could just call `localStorage.clear()`. It clears all data stored

Comment: Up 1 Jack Spairow for a quick dirty fix but obviously no good if you use local storage for other things.